# No paginiation after reRendered Datatable

Tags: visualforce, datatable

So after I have added the `reRender` to the `commandButton` I do not see the pagination and if I remove the reRender the pagination works, after spent good amount of time and could not able to figure out and I'm positive that its not finding the `Id` of the `apex:dataTable` ? so I looked at the developer console the Id that is generating so the `Id` is something like this: `SearchPage:myform:pb1`

So, I tried something like this: but did not work

```
<apex:commandButton value="Rerender table" action="{!abc}" 
                        reRender="SearchPage:myform:pb1"/>
```

Error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('https://xxxx.salesforce.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin ('null').

```
<apex:commandButton value="Rerender table" action="{!abc}" reRender="pb1"/> 
    <apex:pageBlock columns="1" id="pb1"> 
               <apex:dataTable value="{!abc}" var="wrsa"  >
                  ......
                  ......
               </apex:dataTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock >
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a red herring. I think there's something wrong with the VF library, because almost every page I have generates that message at some point. As for the actual cause, the ID value you should be using should be the same as the ID value of whatever you're reRendering, not the generated ID that is used by Visualforce internally. In other words, the code in your question *should* work just fine. I believe something more nefarious is going on, perhaps the location of button versus the location of the apex:dataTable itself. Try targeting the table directly:

```
<apex:commandButton ... reRender="myDataTable">
<apex:dataTable ... id="myDataTable">
```

Pro Tip: If you need to reRender multiple areas, you can provide a comma-separated list of Visualforce ID values.